# Check if mkl correctly installed in python3

Tags: python, windows, numpy, blas

I have tried to install mkl (blas) in python 3.6 (windows 10) and would like to check if I have installed it correctly. When I write numpy.show_config() I get the following message below. Does my numpy now use the mkl(blas) library?

```
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_rt']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/mkl/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_rt']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/mkl/include']
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_rt']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/mkl/include']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_rt']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/mkl/include']

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 'check if has been installed' then try:

```
try:
 import module
except ImportError, e:
 print('ERROR') #module doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can check if the package MKL is installed or not using pip freeze. This will list down all the packages that are installed on the current installation of python.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.